# Why R netCDF4 package is transposing my data?

Tags: r, netcdf

I'm reading a .nc data in R with ncdf4 and RNetCDF. The NetCDF metadata says that there are 144 lons and 73 lats, which leads to 144 columns and 73 rows, right?

However, the data I get in R seems to be transposed with 144 rows and 73 columns.

Please could you tell me what is wrong?

thanks

```
    library(ncdf4)
    a <- tempfile()
    download.file(url = "ftp://ftp.cdc.noaa.gov/Datasets/ncep.reanalysis2.derived/pressure/uwnd.mon.mean.nc", destfile = a)
    nc <- nc_open(a)
    uwnd <- ncvar_get(nc = ncu, varid = "uwnd")
    dim(uwnd)
    ## [1] 144  73  17 494
    umed <- (uwnd[ , , 10, 421] + uwnd[ , , 10, 422] + uwnd[ , , 10, 423])/3
    nrow(umed)
    ## [1] 144
    ncol(umed)
    ## [1] 73
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks you are having two problems.

***The first one*** is related with expecting the same structure that the netCDF file has in R which is a problem in itself because when you are translating the multi-dimensional array structure of the netCDF into 2 dimensional dataframe. NetCDF format needs some reshaping in R in order to be manipulated as it does in python(see: http://geog.uoregon.edu/bartlein/courses/geog490/week04-netCDF.html).

***The second one*** is that you are using values instead of indices when subsetting the data.

```
umed <- (uwnd[ , , 10, 421] + uwnd[ , , 10, 422] + uwnd[ , , 10, 423])/3
```

**The solution** that I see for this is starting by creating the indices of the dimensions that you want to subset. In this example I am subsetting preassure level 10 millibar and all that goes between longitude 230 and 300 and latitude 25 and 40.

```
nc <- nc_open("uwnd.mon.mean.nc")

LonIdx <- which( nc$dim$lon$vals > 230 & nc$dim$lon$vals <300 )
## [1]  94  95  96  97  98  99 100 101 102 103 104 105 106 107 108 109 110 111 112 113         
## 114 115 116 117 118 119 120
LatIdx <- which( nc$dim$lat$vals >25  & nc$dim$lat$vals < 40)
## [1] 22 23 24 25 26
LevIdx <- which( nc$dim$level$vals==10)
## [1] 17
```

Then you would need to apply the indices over each dimension except time which i would assume you don't want to subset. Sub setting lon and latitude is important due to R saves all in memory therefore leaving the whole range of them would consume a significant amount of RAM.

```
lat <- ncvar_get(nc,"lat")[LatIdx]
lon <- ncvar_get(nc,"lon")[LonIdx] 
lev <- ncvar_get(nc,"level")[LevIdx]
time <- ncvar_get(nc,"time")
```

After that you can get the variable that you were looking for *uwnd Monthly U-wind on Pressure Levels* and finish reading the netCDF file with a `nc_close(nc)`.

```
uwnd <- ncvar_get(nc,"uwnd")[LonIdx,LatIdx,LevIdx,] 
nc_close(nc)
```

At the end you can expand the grid with all the four dimensions: longitude,latitude,preassure level and time.

```
uwndf <- data.frame(as.matrix(cbind(expand.grid(lon,lat,lev,time))),c(uwnd))
names(uwndf) <- c("lon","lat","level","time","U-wind")
```

Bind it to a dataframe with the U-wind variable and convert the netcdf time variable into an R time object.

```
uwndf$time_final<-convertDateNcdf2R(uwndf$time, units = "hours", origin =          
as.POSIXct("1800-01-01",  tz = "UTC"),time.format="%Y-%m-%d %Z %H:%M:%S")
```

At the end you will have the dataframe you are looking for between Jan 1979 and March 2020.

```
max(uwndf$time_final)
## [1] "2020-03-01 UTC"
min(uwndf$time_final)
## [1] "1979-01-01 UTC"
head(uwndf)
##     lon  lat level    time    U-wind time_final
## 1 232.5 37.5    10 1569072  3.289998 1979-01-01
## 2 235.0 37.5    10 1569072  5.209998 1979-01-01
## 3 237.5 37.5    10 1569072  7.409998 1979-01-01
## 4 240.0 37.5    10 1569072  9.749998 1979-01-01
## 5 242.5 37.5    10 1569072 12.009998 1979-01-01
## 6 245.0 37.5    10 1569072 14.089998 1979-01-01
```

I hope this is useful! Cheers!

Note: For converting the netcdf time variable into an R time object make sure you have the ncdf.tools library installed.